# Returning a Range with some rows having merged columns in Google Appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am to create a custom function for Google Sheets using Google AppScript. I have a set of data that my custom function will summarize and display the summary on another sheet.

I am able to create my on algorithm for the summary and return a range like this:

**Current**

[image]

Now I understand that an Appscript function returns a two dimensional array, but my problem is how do I merge some of the cells Using Appscript? Whenever there's a month? Like this:

**Target**

[image]

For the example above,
the range I will be returning from my custom function will be

```
[
    ['January', ''],
    ['Project 1', '10 Hours'],
    ['Project 2', '20 Hours'],
    ['Project 3', '30 Hours'],
    ['Project 4', '40 Hours'],
    ['Project 5', '50 Hours'],
    ['February', ''],
    ['Project 1', '10 Hours'],
    ['Project 2', '20 Hours'],
    ['Project 3', '30 Hours'],
    ['Project 4', '40 Hours'],
    ['Project 5', '50 Hours']
]
```

So how do I tell AppScript to tell GooglSheets that `['January', ''],` and `['February', ''],` are cells to be merged?

If there's a function in Excel that can do this, I am also open to other methods. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example copy table from [Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hart2.png) to [Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcnSg.png) to 3 row and 4 column.

```
function myFunction() {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();   
  var mergeRows = [];  
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {    
    if (data[i][1] == "") {
      mergeRows.push(i);      
    }
  }  
  var startRow = 3;  
  var startCol = 4;  
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[1];  
  sheet2.getRange(startRow, startCol, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);  
  for(var i = 0; i < mergeRows.length; i++) {    
    sheet2.getRange(startRow + mergeRows[i], startCol, 1, 2).merge().setHorizontalAlignment('center');
  }  
}
```

Comment: Nice answer Speedy, and I this does help, just one more followup question before I accept this as answer, how do I make `startRow` and `startCol` Dynamic? how do I know which sheet was `myFunction` was used in?

Comment: Not exactly understand about dynamic. Where you want to paste data? To first empty row or after another data? Give me more info please.
About Sheet: you can open Spreadsheet [by id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)) and select Sheet [by name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)).

Comment: When I say Dynamic, it can change at anytime without me hardcoding which cell. Say on `sheet1!A:2` I entered `=myFunction()` so it has to return the result range to that cell. The returning-a-range part was easy but how do I make the function know which cell it was called from? Thanks so much Speedy! That's all I need to know to complete this answer.

Comment: Ignore the followup question, I've found this "[In Google Script, get the spreadsheet cell calling a custom function](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54414/in-google-script-get-the-spreadsheet-cell-calling-a-custom-function)" which I can add to your solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the [`merge()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#merge()) or `mergeAcross()` method.
Something like

```
sheet.getRange('A1:B1').merge();
sheet.getRange('A7:B7').merge();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tovly, but how do I tell Sheets which cell January and which cell February is going to be? The number of projects on either January and February are Dynamic, so they could move arround.